# Using MailGun for ruby on rails application on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, mailgun

I am trying to use MailGun to send emails in my RubyonRails application which is hosted on heroku.

I added the MailGun addon to my heroku application. I updated my `config/environments/production.rb` as below:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :port           => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_PORT'],
    :address        => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_SERVER'],
    :user_name      => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_LOGIN'],
    :password       => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_PASSWORD'],
    :domain         => 'mydomain.herokuapp.com', #mydomain actually contains the realvalue
    :authentication => :plain,
  }
```

I created a file in app/mailers directory:

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "myemail@gmail.com"

  def notify_user(user)
    puts "Going to send email!! to"
    puts user
    mail(to: user, subject: "Welcome!")
  end
end
```

In my application_controller.rb

I have a function:

```
def notify_people()
    puts "Notify people!"
    ApplicationMailer.notify_user("xyz@gmail.com")
    puts "over"
end
```

From one of my other controllers I call notify_people. However in my heroku logs, Notify people! is being printed, and nothing after that. I am not able to understand why it is not able to called notify_user.

My notify_user function is:

class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "abcd@gmail.com"
  #layout 'mailer'
  def notify_user(user)
    puts "Going to send email!! to"
    puts user
    mail(to: user, subject: "Welcome!")
    puts "Done sending mail!"
    return
  end
end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the mailer with `.deliver_later`:

```
ApplicationMailer.notify_user("xyz@gmail.com").deliver_later
```

also, make sure the [ENV variables are set on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) using details from your Mailgun account.

EDIT: You're probably getting an exception from the call to `ApplicationMailer`. Ideally you should troubleshoot that in development, but if needed you can add: `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true` to production.rb to get visibility into what's happening.

Tangentially, instead of print statements take a look at debuggers like byebug and [pry-byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug). They can save you a lot of time troubleshooting.

Comment: Edited with some other suggestions :)

Comment: I added the command you mentioned in my production.rb file. I did not get any error in my heroku logs. However it looks fails after calling the mail function as nothing after that gets printed.

Comment: Are you able to send email from the app at all? Are you calling the mailer with `deliver_later`? Have you set the 4 environment variables above on Heroku? can you confirm that `notify_user` is executed?

Comment: Yes I am calling with deliver_later. The  4 environment variables are set in Heroku. Yes notify_user has been called.

Comment: Ok. How much of `notify_user` is executed? Could you post the body of `notify_user`, and the [ActionMailer configuration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#example-action-mailer-configuration) from production.rb (with sensitive bits removed!)

Comment: I added notify_user in my question. Action Mailer configuration is already there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91258/discussion-between-thebenedict-and-user1692342).